# How to assign without instantiating

Tags: python

I need to remove a item from a list and then add it again in the same position, like this:

```
x = ['a','b','c']
x2 = ['a','b','c']
x.remove(x[1])
...

x = x2 
x.remove(x[0])
...

#expected result:
x == ['b','c'] #True
x2 == ['a','b','c'] #True

#real result 

1. example == True
2. example == False
```

That happens because when I use `x = x2` I created an instance of `x2` on `x`, but I just wanna assign `x2` raw value to `x`. How can I do it?

Comment: You mean you want to make a copy of `x2` and assign it to `x`?

Comment: "That happens because when I use x = x2 I created an instance of x2 on x," no, that isn't at all what is happening. In fact, the fundamental issue is that you are assigning *the same value*

Comment: Read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
x=x2
```

With:

```
x=x2.copy()
```

Or with:

```
x=x2[:]
```

For it to work.